# dtw(distance.only = TRUE, ...) : No warping path exists that is allowed by costraints

Tags: r, time-series, clustering, distance, hierarchical-clustering

Using the [UCR time-series database](http://www.cs.ucr.edu/~eamonn/time_series_data/) and modification in this code:

```
library(dtw)
set.seed(6218)
n <- 10
#sc <- read.table("/Users/mona/cs799/UCR_TS_Archive_2015/Gun_Point/Gun_Point_TRAIN")
sc <- read.table("~/cs799/UCR_TS_Archive_2015/Gun_Point/Gun_Point_TRAIN", 
                 sep=",", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
s <- sample(1:100, n)
idx <- c(s, 100+s, 200+s, 300+s, 400+s, 500+s)
sample2 <- sc[idx, ]
distance.matrix <- dist(sample2, method="DTW")
observedLabels <- c(rep(1,n), rep(2,n), rep(3,n), rep(4,n), rep(5,n), rep(6,n))
hc <- hclust(distance.matrix, method="average")
plot(hc, labels=observedLabels, main="")
rect.hclust(hc, k=6)
memb <- cutree(hc, k=6)
table(observedLabels, memb)
```

I get this error:

```
distance.matrix <- dist(sample2, method="DTW")
Error in dtw(distance.only = TRUE, ...) : 
  No warping path exists that is allowed by costraints
```

I am new to time series classification and I hope adept people help me learn one thing or two rather than closing the question!

Comment: Is the data set *clean*?

Comment: You have asked a number of questions here, Mona. You should know our policies by now. Coding questions & understanding error messages are off topic here.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that the standard Gun_Point train dataset has 50 observations.

Thus, when you (presumably) randomly sampling from these, i.e., `sample(1:100,...` some of the `sample2` timeseries are just sequences of NAs. Another point is that dataset has labels '1' and '2' for Gun or Point -- these need to be removed before running DTW.

Thanks!